# Nginx configuration for jenkins on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, jenkins, amazon-ec2

Im learning nginx and jenkins by setting up a build server on ec2. Setting up jenkins was easy and I was able to even create a test job. I now want to move on to nginx config and mighty confused as to how to set it up. I have hosted zone with my domain, lets call it domain.com . I created an A record for jenkins.domain.com and in the value box put it the IP of the ec2 instance.

Then added this to the /etc/nginx/site-enabled/default

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jenkins.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name jenkins.domain.com;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://127.0.0.1:8080 https://jenkins.domain.com;

      # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_request_buffering off;
      # workaround for https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45651
      add_header 'X-SSH-Endpoint' 'jenkins.domain.com:50022' always;
    }
  }
```

However when I go to jenkins.domain.com:80 I get the site cannot be reached page...

Comment: Do you mean to redirect all requests to SSL? You don't have an SSL listener configured.

Comment: I generated self signed SSL certs following this tutorial - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: You may have generated the certificates but you still don't have an SSL listener configured, which may be part of your problem. If you comment out the first portion of your configuration (the part that does a 301 redirect) and reload nginx, what happens then? Do you get the same error? What ends up in your `access.log` and `error.log` files?

Comment: You are redirecting everything to port 443 without any configuration for SSL in your nginx config file. 

Ref - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Answer (score 2):

proxy_redirect is not needed here. You can use below site configuration. You should create file jenkins in /etc/nginx/site-available(for ubuntu) or /etc/nginx/conf.d/ (centos or rhel) & copy the configuration in that file. You have to create the soft link on Ubuntu in site-enabled.

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/site-available/jenkins /etc/nginx/site-enabled/jenkins
```

**Jenkins conf file**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name jenkins.domain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx-error.log;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;    
    proxy_read_timeout 150s;
    proxy_next_upstream error;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

    # Add HTTP Strict Transport Security for good measure.
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;";
  }
}
```